# How to assign to a list from another method in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, list

how can I assign to a list from another method? I created WPF Application.

I tried:

```
private static Random number = new Random();
private void count()
{
    int maxfirst = 10;
    int maxsecond = 10;
    int secondc = number.Next(2, maxsecond);
    int firstc = number.Next(1, maxfirst);

    if (mark.Text == "+")
    {
        total = (firstc + secondc);
    }
    else if (mark.Text == "-")
    {
        total = (firstc - secondc);
    }
    else if (mark.Text == "*")
    {
        total = (firstc * secondc);
    }
    else
    {
        firstc = secondc * number.Next(1, maxfirst / secondc);
        int residue = (firstc % secondc);

        if (residue == 0)
        {
            total = (firstc / secondc);
        }
    }
    firstt.Text = firstc.ToString();
    secondt.Text = secondc.ToString();
    result.Text = total.ToString();
}
```

and in another method I have:

```cs
List<string> list = new List<string> { result.Text, "2", "3" };
```

How can i get enough **result.Text** to list? It writes to me: *Compiler Error CS0236-A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property 'field'.*

Thank you for the advice and your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that `list` is a field. I.e. you are not creating the list inside a method, but as a field of a class.

Since you are using a "field initializer", i.e. you are creating your object directly after declaring it, you cannot use any other non-static properties in your class. This is because these field initializers run before the constructor, so other fields, like `result` may not be initialized yet.

To solve this, move your initialization inside an actual method, or the constructor. That should ensure it is run after `result` and other objects are created.

Comment: You're right that I didn't have it inside the method and I came up with an unnecessarily complicated solution. Thank you very much!!!